# jQuery prevent autoplay after user closes video

Tags: html, jquery

I'm writing a script that will pop-up a video and autoplay it following [this example](https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/how-to-add-pop-up-video-into-a-website.stml). Everything is working fine, however when the user closes the video, it continues playing in the background. How can I tell the browser to turn off autoplay after the user closes the video?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline'
  });
});
```

```css
#headerPopup {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}

#headerPopup iframe {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide">
  <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qN3OueBm9F4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet to your question, but right now it fails, since there's no script for `magnificPopup`. If you can find a CDN or location that provides that, you can add it to the HTML, much like I've added jQuery.

Comment: When the window is closed, you can execute the `stop` event for the video. Or `remove` the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, there is no straight forward answer to your problem. This is a common thing people encounter when trying to show videos on websites.

The best approach to do this, is by using the Bootstrap CSS framework, because it has modals (pop ups) where you can add a video and whenever you close or open them it exposes events that can trigger functionalities.

In this case, you need jQuery to do something when opening and closing the modal. To avoid the video from playing on the background when the user closes the modal, one way would be to remove the content of the `src` attribute of the iframe, that will prevent the iframe to continue playing the video. And then when the user opens the modal add the link back. If you don't do this, what will happen is that the user may click on the video one time, it will work fine, but then after jQuery removed the link of the video, it wont work.

**jQuery script I use for this purpose:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            
     // Save the url of the video in a variable
     var url = $("#MyVideo").attr('src');
            
     // When the modal is closed remove the url of the iframe
     $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#MyVideo").attr('src', '');
     });
            
     // When the modal is opened, add the url to the iframe
     $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#MyVideo").attr('src', url);
     });
});
```

You can read more about how Bootstrap modals work [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/). The details and explanations of the events are on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks so much @Gass! I really appreciate you coming up with a solution that will work (instead of just answering the question at hand). I'll try to implement your solution today.

Comment: Your welcome, let me know how it goes and if you encounter any problems drop a line.

Comment: you are amazing, @Gass, it worked!!!

Comment: Thats great @Muriel, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I managed to get the video to play now - on desktop it auto-plays once the user clicks "watch video". Problem is that on mobile the modal pops up, but then the video doesn't auto-play. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: Never done it, I would need to look it up, but this goes beyond the scope of the question. Maybe try searching on Stack or making a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Gass - I managed to figure it out. You need to use <video> with "playsinline" instead of iframe. Posted and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039353/how-to-auto-play-a-pop-up-video-on-ios/70068492#70068492