# How to auto-play a pop-up video on IOS

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to autoplay a video in a pop-up once the user clicks "watch video". Right now my code is working fine on desktop, but on mobile (IOS) the video iframe opens but doesn't autoplay. I'm currently using a bootstrap modal and attaching & removing the video source on the click events, like this:

```
<a href="#headerPopup" id="headerVideoLink" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"> Watch Video </a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <iframe width="100" height="180" id="myVideo" src="../static/img/videos/Whatsfordinner with filter.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Save the url of the video in a variable
   var url = $("#myVideo").attr('src');

   // When the modal is closed remove the url of the iframe
   $("#videoModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
      $("#myVideo").attr('src', '');
   });

   // When the modal is opened, add the url to the iframe
   $("#videoModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
      $("#myVideo").attr('src', url);
   });
});
```

Should I be using a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now - you need to use video instead of iframe. Here's my code for those interested:

```
<a href="#headerPopup" id="headerVideoLink" target="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">
    <div class="watch-now">
      <img src="../static/img/Watch_Video.png" alt="Watch Video">
  </div>
</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <video autoplay playsinline id="myVideo">
                <source src="../static/img/videos/Whatsfordinner with filter.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Save the url of the video in a variable
   var url = "../static/img/videos/Whatsfordinner with filter.mp4";

   // When the modal is closed remove the url of the iframe
   $("#videoModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
      $("#myVideo").attr('src', '');
   });

   // When the modal is opened, add the url to the iframe
   $("#videoModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
      $("#myVideo").attr('src', url);
   });
```

Hope this helps someone out there!